# ¿Por qué no se reconoce el método Contains en LINQ a Entidades?

Tags: c#, linq

Estoy trabajando con LINQ y quiero hacer una consulta que me traiga todas las palabras que contengan "man" pero no me reconoce el método `Contains`

```
IEnumerable<Product> producto = context.Products.Where(
            p => p.Contains("man"));
```

¿De qué manera lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Creo que ese `p` es un `Product` y deberías comparar si algún campo en él es el que posee `"man"` como parte de su contenido.

Comment: Lo que menciona Luiggi es correcto, probablemente debas de cambiar `Product` a `string` o `p.algunaPropiedad.Contains("man")`

Comment: Hola carlos quedaría    IEnumerable<string> producto = context.Products.Where(
                p => p.ProductName.Contains("man"));  el error me dice que no se puede convertir IQueryable a IEnumerable ya hay una conversion.

Comment: @PedroÁvila Tienes que declarar la variable como `IEnumerable<Product>` o `var` **no** como `IEnumerable<string>` a menos que estés usando `Select` para obtener solo los nombres.

Comment: Gracias Equiso.

Comment: Puedes colocar el código de `Product` ?

Comment: IEnumerable<Product> producto = context.Products.Where(
                p => p.ProductName.Contains("man"));  no se como darle formato para que salga como código

Comment: Hola Pedro me refiero al código de la clase `Product` y por favor edita tu pregunta, no lo dejes como comentario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es evaluar la frase "man" en todas las columnas de tipo string, puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
var productos = context.Products.Where(
        p => p.Name.Contains("man") 
            || p.Description.Contains("man")
            || p.AttributeN.Contains("man")
        ).ToList();
```

Para recórrelo ten en cuenta el ToList() que se puso al final y la declaración con la palabra var. Ahora para recorrerlo haz lo siguiente:

```
foreach(var item in productos)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Nombre:" + item.Name);
}
```

Comment: Como hago para que lo muestre, me traiga todos los que tienen la palabra man, soy principiante en linq

Comment: Me puedes dar mas detalles sobre lo que quieres hacer. No se si te refieres a mostrárselos al usuario final? si es así, es aplicación Web o de escritorio?

Comment: Solo quiero verlo yo depurandolo hare un foreach

Comment: @PedroÁvila, OK. Entonces te voy a poner el código en la misma respuesta. Apenas estoy empezando a manejar esta herramienta y no veo como poner código dentro de los comentarios

Comment: Utiliza el caracter ` para poder marcar algo como comentario. Puedes ver el boton de ayuda abajo del boton "Añadir comentario". Aunque casi siempre es mejor editar la respuesta o pregunta para agregar este tipo de cosas

Comment: @jasilva muchas gracias, lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima ocasión

Answer (score 0):

Después del punto de "p" te hace falta la columna sobre la cual actuará el contains:

```
p => p.Nombre.Contains("aquí")
```

Con eso lo lograrás.